# MySQL nested join across many tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have table for transactions, transaction_properties, transaction_inventories. inventories.

```
`transactions:`
id, name, qty

`transaction_properties:`
transaction_id, property_id

`transaction_inventory:`
transaction_id, inventory_id

`inventories:`
id, name, property_id
```

My task is to get all transaction according my property id.
property_id gets data from inventory that gets data from transaction_inventory, also gets data from transaction_properties and finally I get all `transaction_ids` to get them from `transaction` table.
Please do not consider to change table architecture. This style is a must for this project.

Comment: Great! Good luck. Welcome back if you run into any problems.

Comment: Hint: You can add as many `JOIN ... ON ...` clauses as you want. You will probably have to specify the names of tables with the columns, as you have many similar names, e.g. `transactions.id = transaction_properties.transaction_id`

Answer (score 0):

Check the following query:

```
select inv.*,t.*,tran_pro.*,tran_inv.* from inventories as inv 
left join on transation as t on t.id on tran_pro.transtaion_id
left join on transaction_properties as tran_pro on t.id = tran_pro.transaction_id
left join on transaction_invertory as tran_inv on t.id = tran_inv.transaction_id
where inv.property_id = ''
```

Note:Keep all ids as primary key

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, it should be fairly simple if you have attempted to solve the problem or looked up how joins work. Unless I am missing any other detail.

`select t.id, t.name, invt.id, tp.property_id
from inventories invt
inner join transactions_inventory ti
on invt.id = ti.inventory_id
inner join transaction_properties tp
on tp.transaction_id = ti.transaction_id
inner join transactions t
on t.id = tp.transaction_id`

Comment: your sample did not worked. I solved by myself. thank you